# Join String based on coordinates Python

Tags: python

I am using ocr api ([mindee.com](https://mindee.com)), where I give handwritten notes in image format and in response I get the extracted words with confidence and coordinates.
Below is the sample of response.

```
[
{'confidence': 0.51, 
 'content': 'review',
 'polygon': [[0.062, 0.867], [0.176, 0.867], [0.175, 0.894], [0.06, 0.894]]
}, 
{'confidence': 0.56, 
 'content': 'with', 
 'polygon': [[0.209, 0.869], [0.295, 0.869], [0.295, 0.9], [0.208, 0.9]]
},
{'confidence': 0.53, 
 'content': 'reports',
 'polygon': [[0.334, 0.877], [0.455, 0.877], [0.454, 0.918], [0.333, 0.918]]
}
]
```

These content/extracted words are unordered. So I cannot loop and join the string.
coordinates are given, So I thought to join string based on it but not getting any idea.

Can you please explain theoretically or pseudocode how to work with it. I will implement.

Answer (score 0):

> These content/extracted words are unordered.

Why do you think that? They are clearly ordered, because they are in a list.
What you need to do is just iterate through the list and take the 'content' each iteration to get the word and join the words together.

If you need the code, just ask :)

Comment: Maybe @HemantSah meant they are not in a useful order :)

Comment: @Thomas Maybe that's true, but I think that they are in the correct order, because if you look at  x coordinates of the polygons, they are always increasing..

Comment: Building text from this result is pain. @mbostic said I can just iterate and join the words but what about new lines?

Comment: @HemantSah Getting new lines would be a bit more difficult. But do you really need it? Can't you just join the words with spaces?

Comment: My task is to digitize the handwritten notes and extract useful keywords out of it.
extracting does not require order for me, but digitizing requires so it makes some sense if anyone reads it.